# Creating divs dynamically with inline style using ngFor but with a condition using ngIf in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular component in which I am dynamically creating divs using `ngFor`, I also want to check a condition before creating a div but I am not able to use `ngFor` and `ngIf` in the same the div.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let row of equips" 
      style="padding-top: 7pt; padding-left: 10px; width : 100%">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create a div based on a property of `row` of `equips`. I tried with

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let row of equips"  *ngIf = "row.conf == 'Y'"
      style="padding-top: 7pt; padding-left: 10px; width : 100%">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

but realised cannot use 2 directives in same divs. I have tried with

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let row of equips"  
      style="padding-top: 7pt; padding-left: 10px; width : 100%">
      <div *ngIf = "row.conf == 'Y'">
       ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but this is creating empty divs. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular do not allow us to use `ngFor` and `ngIf` within a single element due to obvious reason that it will create problem to calculate DOM element which will be rendered on the browser.

So, we need to make sure both of them are used in a seperate elements, in parent-child pattern like:

```html
<parent-element *ngIf="condition">
   <child-element *ngFor="condition">
     {{do somethint}}
   </child-element>
</parent-element>
```

But this way the parent element will also be added in the DOM, which is not ideal for some cases.

So to overcome the issue of unnecessary DOM element, we can use `ng-container` element which is provided by Angular for this scenario (and some templating stuff which is beyond our discussion).

PS: You can simply update your code like below to solve your issue of extra DOM element.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let row of equips"  
      style="padding-top: 7pt; padding-left: 10px; width : 100%">
      <ng-container *ngIf = "row.conf == 'Y'">
       ...
      </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```html
<!-- if you want to hide the div -->
<div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of equips">
      <div class="col-3" *ngIf = "row.conf == 'Y'" style="padding-top: 7pt; padding-left: 10px; width : 100%">
       ...
      </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

More Info:

Coming back to the issue, let me be a little more clear.
We can use `<ng-container>` like any other element and add any one of `ngIf` or `ngFor` on it.
For your case you need to wrap the div inside the `ng-container` which contains the `ngFor` statement, and apply `ngIf` on the child `div` element.
This was it won't show any div if it doesn't match the criteria as show in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7yeam)

Happy Coding.

Comment: For some reason still getting those empty divs

Comment: Can you attach the image link and the element tree? So that I can check the exact issue.

Comment: I tried replicating in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsrfhk

Comment: Oh, got it.
`<ng-container>` can be used either as a parent or a child based on the scenario.
I have updated my answer. Attaching the stackblitz link 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7yeam

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-container` which won't create an empty div.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let ele of data">
  <div class="col-3" *ngIf="ele.symbol == 'Y'">
    {{ele.name}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re4jhf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Or you can filter your array beforehand:

**ts**

```
filteredEquips: any[];

ngOnInit() {
   this.filteredEquips = this.equips.filter(e => e.conf === 'Y');
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="col-3" *ngFor="let row of filteredEquips">
  {{ row.name}}
</div>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hdjidy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Or you can even create a dedicated `@Pipe` for that.

Comment: still getting those empty divs

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: In the first stackblitz shared, if any of the config is changed to `N` empty space is created

Comment: I updated the answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re4jhf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html